# error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know about O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US

Tags: corda

I am facing an error while starting a flow in IOU sample cordapp against enterprise trial 4.0 version and Azure SQL as the node db.

```
**error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know about O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US**
```

I executed "run networkMapSnapshot" and i can see "party b" like below:

```
addresses:
  "localhost:10008"
  legalIdentitiesAndCerts:
   "O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US"
  platformVersion: 4
  serial: 1560174116122
```

Comment: When you say running, have you deployed the nodes and running a flow, or are you running unit tests?

Comment: yes, nodes  are deployed and I get this error when I issue this statement from PartyA node:

start IOUFlow iouValue: 99, otherParty: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"

Comment: I tried the same with local sql server instance and it works fine but not with azure sql.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is likely not an azure or SQL issue.

I'd take another look at this one and see if you can share more information with us about the node configuration and permissions between the nodes you're creating. 
When running nodes locally there's a lot of different barriers that are removed when comparing with a cloud provider.

If you're able to run the exact same flow/node config on both your local machine and the cloud with the same node config; then I'd take some time to think over what configuration options are configured in the cloud provider.